# HTML5 placeholder disappears on focus

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, safari, focus, placeholder

Is there a freely available jQuery plugin that changes `placeholder` behavior to match HTML5 spec?

**Before Focus**
[image: chrome unfocused placeholder]

**On Focus Good (Safari)**
[image: safari focused placeholder]

**On Focus Bad (Chrome, Firefox)**
[image: chrome focused placeholder]

You can what your browser does [with this simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqaUw/).

[HTML5 draft spec says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute):

> User agents should present this hint to the user, after having stripped line breaks from it, when the element's value is the empty string **and/or** the control is not focused (e.g. by displaying it inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise).

The "/or" is new in current draft so I suppose that's why Chrome and Firefox don't support it yet. See [WebKit bug #73629](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73629), [Chromium bug #103025](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103025).

Comment: Your fiddle works for me (placeholder doesn't disappear on focus) on Chrome 17.0.963.12.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff, Chrome says 16.0.921 is the last version available for me (might be because of localization or different channel). Anyway, I'm looking for a JS fix that will work for older versions.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff where did you find Chrome 17? Do they provide nightlies?

Comment: @antisanity I'm on the dev channel: http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: By the way, there's also a related [Firefox bug #673873](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=673873).

Comment: I have recently updated my [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) polyfill to support this. Works in pretty much all browsers, including IE6, and has no dependency on jQuery.

Comment: Surely "e.g. by displaying it inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise" means that this behaviour is allowed by the spec. I'd also suggest that having the placeholder text hidden on focus is far more usable for most people (I've watched several people try to select the placeholder text to delete it before typing).

Comment: Why not trust that the browser is doing the right job? The browser knows what's best way better than the developer (each browser can be configured to the user's likings).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: Stefano labels]

[Stefano J. Attardi](http://attardi.org/) wrote a nice jQuery plugin that just does that.
It is more stable than Robert's and also fades to a lighter grey when the field gets focused.

- See [the demo page](http://attardi.org/labels2/)
- Grab it on [GitHub](https://github.com/steadicat/labels)
- Play with [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSypb/2/)

---

I modified his plugin to read `placeholder` attribute as opposed to manually creating a `span`.
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSypb/6/) has complete code:

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello, world!">
```

#### JS

```
// Original code by Stefano J. Attardi, MIT license

(function($) {
    function toggleLabel() {
        var input = $(this);

        if (!input.parent().hasClass('placeholder')) {
            var label = $('<label>').addClass('placeholder');
            input.wrap(label);

            var span = $('<span>');
            span.text(input.attr('placeholder'))
            input.removeAttr('placeholder');
            span.insertBefore(input);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            var def = input.attr('title');
            if (!input.val() || (input.val() == def)) {
                input.prev('span').css('visibility', '');
                if (def) {
                    var dummy = $('<label></label>').text(def).css('visibility','hidden').appendTo('body');
                    input.prev('span').css('margin-left', dummy.width() + 3 + 'px');
                    dummy.remove();
                }
            } else {
                input.prev('span').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }, 0);
    };

    function resetField() {
        var def = $(this).attr('title');
        if (!$(this).val() || ($(this).val() == def)) {
            $(this).val(def);
            $(this).prev('span').css('visibility', '');
        }
    };

    var fields = $('input, textarea');

    fields.live('mouseup', toggleLabel); // needed for IE reset icon [X]
    fields.live('keydown', toggleLabel);
    fields.live('paste', toggleLabel);
    fields.live('focusin', function() {
        $(this).prev('span').css('color', '#ccc');
    });
    fields.live('focusout', function() {
        $(this).prev('span').css('color', '#999');
    });

    $(function() {
       $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').each(
           function() { toggleLabel.call(this); }
       );
    });

})(jQuery);
```

#### CSS

```
.placeholder {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.placeholder span {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #999;
}
.placeholder input, .placeholder textarea {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  font: inherit;
}

/* Hack to remove Safari's extra padding. Remove if you don't care about pixel-perfection. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .placeholder input, .placeholder textarea { padding: 4px; }
}
```

Comment: Seems decent, but the github repo wasn't updated in two years ... I'm reluctant to use stale code.

Comment: @ripper: Could this possibly mean that the code just works? I suggest you try to use it, and if you find any problems, feel free to fork it and fix them. But if you find a better solution, please let us know.

Comment: It could mean that ... it's just not very confidence-inspiring ... but I guess I'll give it a spin.

Comment: @ripper: It worked for me fairly well, except for some font size issues I can't recall exactly.

Comment: A caveat: This requires a lot of CSS, and some of it interferes with my own. Some other plugins I've seen don't require any CSS to function (although I admit I found none that solves the focus problem).

Comment: you also need fields.live('mouseup', toggleLabel); to show the placeholder when user clicks on the reset ([X]) icon in IE

Comment: "live" is deprecated. For current versions of JQuery, replace all instances of "live" with "on"

Answer (score 4):

Robert Nyman discusses the problem and documents his approach [in his blog](http://robertnyman.com/2011/05/02/html5-placeholder-and-an-alternative-approach-introducing-roberts-playground/).
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYbFA/) that has all the neccessary HTML, CSS and JS.

[image]

Unfortunately, he solves the problem by changing `value`.
This will not work by definition if `placeholder` text is itself a valid input.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question by googling out the solution to the same problem. It seems that existing plugins either don't work in elder browsers or hide placeholder on focus.

So I decided to roll on my own solution while trying to combine best parts from existing plugins.

You may check it out [here](https://github.com/w0rm/jquery.placeholder) and open an issue if you face any problems.

Comment: Andrew this is awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks for saving me time & having to do it myself :)

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple like this? On focus save out the placeholder attribute value and remove the attribute entirely; on blur, put the attribute back:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus( function(){
  $(this).attr("data-placeholder",$(this).attr('placeholder')).removeAttr("placeholder");
});
$('input[type="text"]').blur( function(){
  $(this).attr("placeholder",$(this).attr('data-placeholder'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own css3 only solution. See if that fullfills all your needs.

http://codepen.io/fabiandarga/pen/MayNWm

This is my solution:

1. the input element is set to "required"
2. an aditional span element for the placeholder is needed. This element is moved on top of the input element (position: absolute;)
3. with css selectors the input element is tested for validity (required fields are invalid as long as there is no input) and the placeholder is then hidden.

**Pitfall:** The placeholder is blocking mouseevents to the input! This problem is circumvented by hiding the placeholder element when the mouse is inside the parent (wrapper).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input txpe="text" autofocus="autofocus" required/>
  <span class="placeholder">Hier text</span>
</div>

.placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
  color: #A1A1A1;
}
input:invalid + .placeholder {
  display: block;  /* show the placeholder as long as the "required" field is empty */
}
.wrapper:hover .placeholder {
  display: none; /* required to guarantee the input is clickable */
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with Float Label Pattern :)

See [Float labels in CSS](http://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/)