# Html PlaceHolder - How to prevent html PlaceHolder disappearing when focusing on an input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, input, opera

Please have a look at this page using Opera

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

as soon as you focus the PlaceHolder disappears.

I would need to keep the PlaceHolder in place on Opera till the user do not enter some text, as would be on Chrome browser.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I guess you are using some vintage opera

Comment: Why does it matter if it goes away when the user starts to type or when they focus the element? Different browsers handle it differently, let people have the browser behaviour they expect from their browser.

Comment: Also, if you are still looking to support vintage browsers, here you go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574356/html5-placeholder-disappears-on-focus

Comment: Incidentally, that page (as is traditional for W3Schools) is awful. The placeholder attribute is *explicitly* **not** a substitute for a label. It should be used for hints and examples. (`<label> First Name <input name="first" placeholder="John"></label>`)

Comment: As per the [W3 standards](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) it should disappear anyway. **User agents should present this hint to the user, after having stripped line breaks from it, when the element's value is the empty string and the control is not focused, i.e., by displaying it inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise.**